# [HTML][Express] app crashing when using npm start in terminal

Tags: html, node.js, express

Below is my code and the package.json
I have looked at similar questions but the error codes given were different than mine. What can I do to prevent crashing and get the app to run?

Should open a local site with a home page that allows navigation to a different site with a table that lists a few stocks and prices.

package.json

```
  "name": "assignment3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

my code

```
const PORT = 3000;

// The variable stocks has the same value as the variable stocks in the file 'stocks.js'
const stocks = require('./stocks.js').stocks;

const express = require("express");
const app = express();


app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static('public'));
// Note: Don't add or change anything above this line.

// Add your code here

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
    });

app.get('/listing', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+ '/stocklist.html'))
     })

app.get('/sort', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+ '/listingorder.html'))
     })

app.post('/placeorder', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
res.status(200).send("Placed")
})

app.get('/asc', function(req, res){
    let sorted = stocks.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price);
    });
    res.status(200).send({stock: sorted})
 })

app.get('/dsc', function(req, res){
   let sorted = stocks.sort(function(a, b) {
       return parseFloat(b.price) - parseFloat(a.price);
   });
   res.status(200).send({stock: sorted})
})

app.get('/stocks', function(req, res) {
    //var data = {stock: stocks};
    res.status(200).send({stock: stocks});
})
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});


index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <><head>

    </head><body>
            <p>Home Page</p>
            <a href="http://localhost:3000/listing">Stocks</a>

            <a href="http://localhost:3000/sort">Order by low high</a>

            <script>

            </script>

        </body><html>

            stocklist.html

            <html>


                <head>

                </head>

                <body>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        function load(){fetch('http://localhost:3000/stocks')
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(
                                (data) => {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    generate_table(data);
                                }
                            )};
                        }


                        function generate_table(data) {
                            // get the reference for the body
                        }
// get the reference for the body
                        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

// creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
                            var tbl = document.createElement("table");
                            var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
                            var row = document.createElement("tr");
                            var cell = document.createElement("th");
                            var cellText = document.createTextNode("Company");
                            cell.appendChild(cellText);
                            row.appendChild(cell);
                            var cell = document.createElement("th");
                            var cellText = document.createTextNode("Price");
                            cell.appendChild(cellText);
                            row.appendChild(cell);
                            var cell = document.createElement("th");
                            var cellText = document.createTextNode("Symbol");
                            cell.appendChild(cellText);
                            row.appendChild(cell);
                            tblBody.appendChild(row);
                            // creating all cells
                            for (var i = 0; i <data.stock.length />; i++) {
                                // creates a table row
                            }
// creates a table row
                            var row = document.createElement("tr");


                            var cell = document.createElement("td");
                            var cellText = document.createTextNode(data.stock[i].company);
                            cell.appendChild(cellText);
                            row.appendChild(cell);

                            var cell = document.createElement("td");
                            var cellText = document.createTextNode(data.stock[i].price);
                            cell.appendChild(cellText);
                            row.appendChild(cell);

                            var cell = document.createElement("td");
                            var cellText = document.createTextNode(data.stock[i].symbol);
                            cell.appendChild(cellText);
                            row.appendChild(cell);

                            // add the row to the end of the table body
                            tblBody.appendChild(row);
                            }

// put the <tbody> in the <table>
                                tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
// appends <table> into <body>
                                    body.appendChild(tbl);
                                    // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
                                    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
                                    }


                                    load();

                                    function postForm(ev){ev.preventDefault()};
                                    let body = {symbol}: document.getElementById("symbol").value,
                                    qty: document.getElementById("qty").value,
                                    }
                                    console.log(body);
                                    fetch("http://localhost:3000/placeorder", {
                                        // Adding method type
                                        method}: "POST",
                                    body:body,

                                    })

                                    .then(response => response.json())

                                    .then(json => console.log(json));
                                    }
                                </script>
                                    <br />
                                    <form onsubmit="postForm($event)">
                                        Symbol: <input type="text" id="symbol"></>
                                    </form>

                                    <br />
                                    <br />

                                </body>


                            </html>

                                listingorder.html

                                <html>


                                    <head>

                                    </head>

                                    <body>
                                        <div>
                                        </div>
                                        <script>
                                            function load(){fetch('http://localhost:3000/stocks')
                                                .then(response => response.json())
                                                .then(
                                                    (data) => {
                                                        console.log(data);
                                                        generate_table(data);
                                                    }
                                                )};
                                            }


                                            function generate_table(data) {
                                                // get the reference for the body
                                            }
// get the reference for the body
                                            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

// creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
                                                var tbl = document.createElement("table");
                                                var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
                                                var row = document.createElement("tr");
                                                var cell = document.createElement("th");
                                                var cellText = document.createTextNode("Company");
                                                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                                                row.appendChild(cell);
                                                var cell = document.createElement("th");
                                                var cellText = document.createTextNode("Price");
                                                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                                                row.appendChild(cell);
                                                var cell = document.createElement("th");
                                                var cellText = document.createTextNode("Symbol");
                                                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                                                row.appendChild(cell);
                                                tblBody.appendChild(row);
                                                // creating all cells
                                                for (var i = 0; i <data.stock.length />; i++) {
                                                    // creates a table row
                                                }
// creates a table row
                                                var row = document.createElement("tr");


                                                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                                                var cellText = document.createTextNode(data.stock[i].company);
                                                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                                                row.appendChild(cell);

                                                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                                                var cellText = document.createTextNode(data.stock[i].price);
                                                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                                                row.appendChild(cell);

                                                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                                                var cellText = document.createTextNode(data.stock[i].symbol);
                                                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                                                row.appendChild(cell);

                                                // add the row to the end of the table body
                                                tblBody.appendChild(row);
                                                }

// put the <tbody> in the <table>
                                                    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
// appends <table> into <body>
                                                        body.appendChild(tbl);
                                                        // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
                                                        tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
                                                        }


                                                        load();

                                                        function postForm(ev){ev.preventDefault()};
                                                        let body = {symbol}: document.getElementById("symbol").value,
                                                        qty: document.getElementById("qty").value,
                                                        }
                                                        console.log(body);
                                                        fetch("http://localhost:3000/placeorder", {
                                                            // Adding method type
                                                            method}: "POST",
                                                        body:body,

                                                        })

                                                        .then(response => response.json())

                                                        .then(json => console.log(json));
                                                        }
                                                    </script>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <form onsubmit="postForm($event)">
                                                            Symbol: <input type="text" id="symbol"></>
                                                        </form>

                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />

                                                    </body>
function StocksByPrice(){
    if (Number(x.table) > Number(y.table)) {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
}
}
                                                </html>


// Note: Don't add or change anything below this line.
app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`)};
});
```

When running npm start I get this error

```
> assignment3@1.0.0 start D:\Comp Sci\CS 290 Web Development\Assignment 3
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.13
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
D:\Comp Sci\CS 290 Web Development\Assignment 3\server.js:63
<!DOCTYPE html>
          ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Is your HTML _actually_ inside your server.js file?

Comment: @Phix yes the html is inside the server.js file

Comment: I'd take a few steps back to grasp express and how it works. You can't plop html code inside a JS file

Answer (score 0):

I would try and create a 'view' folder and render pages from there. Did you try that?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to begin doing that. I'm only a few weeks into this. I tried googling but that only got me results on how to change the format files are presented in the explorer.

Comment: How your project structure looks like? I mean your folders. And what is the point of your project?

Answer (score 0):

**Sample of the `server.js` file **

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path")

// App constants
const PORT = 3000
const app = express();
// App middlewares
app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")));
// app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "./views/"));

// App routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/views/index.html"))
})
// App server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  const message = `Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`;
  console.log(message);
});
```

In your root directory create a views directory, import the `path` module in your server file. Create a folder named `views` add your `index.html` inside the `views` directory and send files as I have shown in the code snippet shown above. The `views` folder will hold all your HTML files so that you don't mix HTML files with javascript files. Alternatively, you can check out some templating engines like `pug`, `ejs`, or `handlebars` for writing your views

### My directory structure

[image: Directory structure]

Comment: Your directory structure matters a lot. so for this without much folder setup. just one javascript file and the views directory is enough to get you going. On the growth of the project is when now you may create an `src` folder for holding your files. My goal is to keep it simple and easy to implement